# Get selected item from a dropdown menue

Tags: php, html

Hello guys I really need some help with my final year project that I'm working on this the code of the dropdown that contains options from the database

```
<div class="dropdown">
<select class="dropbtn">
<div class="dropdown-content">
<option>Client </option>
<?php
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=facture;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$client = $bdd->query('SELECT nomC FROM client ORDER BY ID ASC');
while ($donnes = $client->fetch())
{
echo "<option value='".$donnes["nomC"]."'>".$donnes["nomC"]."</option>"; 
}
?>
</div>
  </select>
 </div>
    </div>
```

I want to get the selected option from the dropdown and show it on another page.
can I put the selected option in variable and then put it in the database?

Comment: If you put the drop-down within a form and then submit the form, the selected value in the drop-down will be passed back to the server script.. I suggest finding basic PHP forms tutorial if you don't know anything about this kind of thing

Comment: okay, I will try thank you.